# Protocol used between HiveServer HiveMetaStore

Tags: hive

Please, What is the protocole used by HiveServer to communicate with Hive MetaStore ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The hiveclient, Thrift which are used for the hiveserver connection uses the TCP/http protocol.

This [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2) show how the hive server is being setuped which says the usage of TCP.

Comment: thanks for you replay, but i'm not asking about hiveClient, i'm more asking about HiveServer and the service HiveMetaStore